# React native is pushing images to firebase storage with content type: application/octet-stream rather than image/jpeg

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a react native project and I am currently working on completing the profile picture screen. Right now I have a screen and on the screen the user can click on select profile picture which opens up the users gallery or image library for the user to select his profile picture. That works fine and the user can select and confirm an image. The next step is to push that image that was selected to firebase storage. I am running into the issue in which the image is alwasy pushed to firebase storage with the `ContentType:application/octet-stream`. The problem is that when I go to display the image in the users profile page, it does not display the image. I realized that when the url is accessed, it tries to download the image rather than view the image. I need to somehow set the image `ContentType:image/jpeg`. I tried everything and no matter what, it stays as the original content type and will not convert so that it is viewable not downloadable.

here is the component that I have right now:

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
...

import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import {auth, db, storage} from '../../../Utils/Firebase';
import {addDoc, collection} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {getDownloadURL, ref, updateMetadata, uploadBytes} from 'firebase/storage';

const ProfilePictureScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  ...

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  const createUserAccount = (): void => {
    ...
  };

  const createUserProfile = (userId: String, url: string): void => {
    ...
  };
  

  // This is where the image is being uploaded to firebase storage.

  const uploadImage = (userId: string): void => {
    const imageRef = ref(
      storage,
      `ProfilePictures/${profilePicture.fileName}`,
    );
    const metadata = {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    };
    uploadBytes(imageRef, profilePicture, {customMetadata: metadata})
      .then(response => {
        getDownloadURL(imageRef)
          .then(url => {
            console.log('pushed to storage')
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting download URL:', error);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      });
  };

  const pickImage = () => {
    (async function () {
      const galleryStatus =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(galleryStatus.status === 'granted');
    })();
  };

  const pickDirectImage = async () => {
    pickImage();
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [5, 5],
      quality: 1,
    });
    let selectedImage = result.assets[0];
    selectedImage.fileName = `${profileUsername}-profile-picture`;
    console.log(selectedImage);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setProfilePicture(selectedImage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Profile Picture Screen</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pickDirectImage()}>
        <Text>Select Profile Picture</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      ....
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            uploadImage();
          }}>
          <Text>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}>
          <Text>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProfilePictureScreen;
```

Here is what the firstbase storage looks like:

[image: image has content type: application/octet-stream]

---

I just need a way to change the `Content Type` from `application/octet-stream` to `image/jpeg`. How can I do that. That is the only problem I am having. Here is what the profilePicture object looks like. it keeps pushing as a `application/octet-stream`

profilePictureObject:

```
{
  "assetId": "CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3/L0/001",
  "base64": null,
  "duration": null,
  "exif": null,
  "fileName": "Dania-profile-picture.jpeg",
  "fileSize": 13727225,
  "height": 3024,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB8866C8-D53D-47DA-99F2-5CD700EF4EE1/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC734A7E-06AB-4D6E-A078-AAE568879878/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FIOweYou-6d1646a9-9f6c-418d-9753-3ce4dce5140a/ImagePicker/37E40F96-AEAC-4002-99B2-7BA2CE5B3BE7.jpg",
  "width": 4032
}
```

Why on earth is it getting pushed as a `application/octet-stream` to firebase storage?

Comment: In the snippet shared, I don't see the part where you are looking to show the retrieved image. Am i missing something here?

Comment: I will add it. I am displaying the image in another file. The problem is that it is not displaying anything. I will update the question @gkrthk